# Alias a spacing value in Tailwind CSS?

Tags: tailwind-css

I have some spacing values that id like to alias eg I have a card component and id like to set the padding with a class like `p-Card` and then in one place update the padding value regardless of how many times the `p-Card` class is used.

In my taiwind.config.css I could set a value:

```
module.exports = {
    theme: {
        extend: {
            spacing: {
                Card: '10px',
            },
        },
    },
};
```

This works but id like to reuse Tailwind's default spacing values so I can easily bump the value up or down and keep with the default scales.

Im currently doing this by importing the default theme object but this feels verbose. Is there a cleaner way?

```
const defaultTheme = require("tailwindcss/defaultTheme");

module.exports = {
    theme: {
        extend: {
            spacing: {
                Card: defaultTheme.spacing["8"],
            },
        },
    },
};
```

I could also add a custom utility style:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer utilities {
    .p-Card {
        @apply p-8
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if theres any functional difference in the two approaches?

Comment: Another approach to consider, more in the utility class idiom as I've experienced it: use `p-8` in your card component. That's more "transparent" (you can tell the padding from only looking at the component markup, no need to refer to the Tailwind config), and helps keep CSS weight down as projects grow (one `.p-8 { padding: 2rem }` in the final CSS instead of `.p-8, .p-Card, .p-Another, .p-More { padding: 2rem }`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is definitely a difference between your two options here.

**TLDR:** With the config file, Tailwind adds many class aliases using the default Tailwind scale at the value of 8, which is `2rem`.

Using the utility will only add that specific class.

##### Config option

When you use the `tailwind.config.js` file to extend the theme with `defaultTheme.spacing["8"]`, you are actually adding the `Card` alias to any property that uses the scale of `"8"`.

This would include `width`, `height`, `margin`, `padding`, `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right`, etc.

###### Example - https://play.tailwindcss.com/8YRgwjJWLy

On the link above, try adding a class with `-Card` and let the autocomplete show you all the possible generated classes. Then look towards the `Generated CSS > Utilties` tab at the bottom to see the aliases.

Naturally, these classes will only be included in your project if you use them.
So file size shouldn't really be an issue, it just opens the door up for those extra aliases to be used.

Like the one comment added, these do show up in autocomplete.

##### Utility option

When you use the Utility method, you are only adding that specific CSS class to the project. It will only be included in  your stylesheet if it exists on a class in the file rendered. This class most likely won't show up in autocomplete, unless you have a plugin that supports that.

###### Example - https://play.tailwindcss.com/9mPlroweW6

Try adding a class with `p-Card` and look at the `Generated CSS > Utilities`, only `padding: 2rem;` shows.
If you add a class with `m-Card` and look at `Generated CSS > Utilities`, it doesn't render.

If you remove the class `p-Card`, you will see it is removed from the Generated CSS.

Both of these options are suffice and functionally will give you an alias of `p-Card`.

###### EDIT

As [@Evanss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/467875/evanss) pointed out, extending `padding` instead of `spacing` in the config file can also be a valid solution.

##### Example - https://play.tailwindcss.com/fzY2Cll38b

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')
module.exports = {
    theme: {
        extend: {
            padding: {
                Card: defaultTheme.spacing["8"],
            },
        },
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps explain the difference. Thanks!

Comment: Great answer although worth noting you could just extend the padding and not all spacings:           extend: {
            padding: {
                Card: defaultTheme.spacing["8"],
            },
        },

Comment: That is definitely worth noting, I edited my answer to include that bit as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the only difference is that the first approach will give you intellisense if you have the VS Code extension. Functionally, they are identical. I don't believe there's any other way to achieve that.

Comment: In WebStorm I actually have intenseness for both by default